# Java - Reading multiple images from a single zip file and eventually turning them into BufferedImage objects.  Good idea?

Tags: java, zip, bufferedimage, bufferedinputstream

I'm working on a game, and I need to load multiple image files (png, gif, etc.) that I'll eventually want to convert into BufferedImage objects.  In my setup, I'd like to load all of these images from a single zip file, "Resources.zip".  That resource file will contain images, map files, and audio files - all contained in various neatly ordered sub-directories.  I want to do this because it will (hopefully) make resource loading easy in both applet and application versions of my program.  I'm also hoping that for the applet version, this method will make it easy for me to show the loading progress of the game resources zip file (which could eventually amount to 10MB depending on how elaborate this game gets, though I'm hoping to keep it under that size so that it's browser-friendly).

I've included my zip handling class below.  The idea is, I have a separate resource handling class, and it creates a ZipFileHandler object that it uses to pull specific resources out of the Resources.zip file.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class ZipFileHandler
{
private ZipFile zipFile;

public ZipFileHandler(String zipFileLocation)
{
    try
    {
        zipFile = new ZipFile(zipFileLocation);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {System.err.println("Unable to load zip file at location: " + zipFileLocation);}
}

public byte[] getEntry(String filePath)
{
    ZipEntry entry = zipFile.getEntry(filePath);
    int entrySize = (int)entry.getSize();
    try
    {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
        byte[] finalByteArray = new byte[entrySize];

        int bufferSize = 2048;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int chunkSize = 0;
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while(true)
        {
            //Read chunk to buffer
            chunkSize = bis.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); //read() returns the number of bytes read
            if(chunkSize == -1)
            {
                //read() returns -1 if the end of the stream has been reached
                break;
            }

            //Write that chunk to the finalByteArray
            //System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, finalByteArray, bytesRead, chunkSize);

            bytesRead += chunkSize;
        }

        bis.close(); //close BufferedInputStream

        System.err.println("Entry size: " + finalByteArray.length);

        return finalByteArray;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("No zip entry found at: " + filePath);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

And I use the ZipFileHandler class like this:

```
ZipFileHandler zfh = new ZipFileHandler(the_resourceRootPath + "Resources.zip");
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(zfh.getEntry("Resources/images/bg_tiles.png"));

    try
    {
        BufferedImage bgTileSprite = ImageIO.read(in);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Could not convert zipped image bytearray to a BufferedImage.");
    }
```

And the good news is, it works!

But I feel like there might be a better way to do what I'm doing (and I'm fairly new to working with BufferedInputStreams).

In the end, my question is this:

Is this even a good idea?

Is there a better way to load a whole bunch of game resource files in a single download/stream, in an applet- AND application-friendly way?

I welcome all thoughts and suggestions!

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're good, good job figuring out all the zip / input stream stuff!

Comment: Thanks!  I was glad that it actually worked, haha.  Hopefully someone else will benefit from this too.

Comment: 1 thing i'd point out - zipping / unzipping is going to be CPU intensive - and images don't always zip well - check to see that the size of your ZIP file is sufficiently smaller than that of unzipped files, and if the diff is not big, you may wanna just concatenate everything instead of zipping.

Comment: Good thought, thanks.  Fortunately, I think the zipping does make a big difference, at least for many of my zipped text files and several image files with a lot of transparent space around the sprites.  File compression aside, with the concatenation, were you suggesting something like one large binary file that I'd read into a byte array, and split up with something like System.arraycopy() ?  Interesting idea!  I'd just need to find a good way of keeping track of all of the individual file lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking multiple resources and putting in them in one compressed file is how several web applications work (i.e. GWT) It is less expensive to load one large file than multiple small ones. This assumes that you are going to use all those resources in your app. If not Lazy loading is also a viable alternative.
That being said, it is usually best to get the app working and then to profile to find where the bottlenecks are. If not you will end up with a lot of complicated code and it will take you a lot longer to get your app working. 10%-20% of the code takes 80-90% of the time to execute. You just don;t know which 10-20% that is until the project is mostly complete.
If your goal is to learn the technologies and tinker, then good going - looks good.

Comment: The good news is, I do indeed plan to use all of the files that I'm loading.  It's a mix of several large tile sprite sheet files, some character sprite files, and a lottttt of xml map files.  I actually just got xml map file loading working too, so things are good for now!  I'm just hoping that I didn't end up doing something that I'll regret later, heh.  But as you've noticed, my other goal is to learn and tinker!  This project is just for fun anyway.  :)

Comment: Oh! And about profiling: Right now, I'm not sure how I'd profile this.  This is a one-time load right at the beginning, and I guess in the end, it comes down to how easily I might be able to do a preloader without this zip method (compared to, say, including files in my main jar).  Either way, I feel like it's important to be able to display a loading status.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Java program, it is usually considered good practice to bundle it as a jar file anyway. So why do not put your classes simply inside this jar file (in directories, of course). Then you can simply use

```
`InputStream stream = MayClass.class.getResourceAsStream(imagePath);`
```

to load the data for each image, instead of having to handle all the zip by yourself (and it also works for jars not actually on the file system, such as http url in applets).

I also assume the jar will be cached, but you should measure and compare the performance to your solution with an external zip file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The thing is, I'd like to avoid putting the resource files in the same file that has to load fully before I can display anything to a user.  If it's a single 10MB jar file, do you know if there's an easy way to do a preloader (that shows something like "...80%..." "...81%..."?  I've done work with Flash in the past, where preloaders are big, but I don't know my way around the java world quite as well.

Comment: You can use multiple jars and then reference them from the first one in the Manifest file.  Also have a look at *jarindex*.